# How to measure image download time in a webpage?

Tags: image, time, download

I need to measure the time taken to load an image from the server on my website. Let's say I have four images on a webpage; I want to display to the visitor the time it took for each image to load.
What are the ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

create a timer so when the user selects download button the timer starts and when the transfer is done stop it and display it.

Comment: forgive me, I need the time it takes to load the image in the browser.